Firebase sendEmailVerification email link is not working
Am working on a react native expo app with firebase, sending verification message to new users using the firebase sendEmailVerification method which seems to send the email verification link to the users provided email address.
The problem is, clicking on the link will open a new browser tab as expected, then load for about 20-30 seconds and then stop with a failed message like "This page cannot be reached" depending on the browser. I have tried several browsers, clear the cache and yet still not working.


Here is a snippet of my code...
async function onSignUp() {
  await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
   .then(({ user }) => sendEmailVerification(user))
   .catch(error => console.log(error.message))
}

The verification link is sent to the user's email. Clicking on the link, the browser gives "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" error instead of verifying the email address as it should be.
What should I do?
